# how to display filtered array json by using regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a json array and i want to filter an json object which **state **keys contains this word "ALTS".

```
<pre>
   $arr = array(
     array(
       "region" => "valore1",
       "price" => "valore11",
        "state" => "declare par /AMG/OMS/FRA/"
     ),
      array(
      "region" => "valore2",
      "price" => "valore22",
       "state" => "declare par /AMG/OMS/ALTS/"
      ),
     array(
        "region" => "valore4",
         "price" => "valore44",
        "state" => "declare par /AMG/OMS/FRA/"
      ),
     array(
       "region" => "valore5",
       "price" => "valore55",
        "state" => "declare par /AMG/OMS/ALTS/"
       ),
    array(
       "region" => "valore3",
        "price" => "valore33",
        "state" => "declare par /AMG/OMS/ALTS/PT"
      )
   );

    $myJsonArray = json_encode($arr);

    echo $myJsonArray;
</pre>
```

I want to find an example of regular expression which filters this array and only returns an array containing objects with a state containing "/ ALTS".
Any ideas ?

Comment: `I want to find an example..` what you tried? Internet is full of examples also in documentation and tutorials and sites like www.regexr.com which explain your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for that. If you find one word you can use `strpos` function.

```
$newArr = [];
$findTerm = '/ALTS/';

foreach($arr as $key => $valArr)
{
  if(strpos($valArrp['state'], $findTerm) !== false) {
    $newArr[] = $valArr;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi @ daremachine, i don't use regex for this example. I test your solution and it's good.very thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I helped.